# synchronysing dependencies between system and application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

The following error

```
You have already activated strscan 3.0.1, but your Gemfile requires strscan 3.0.3.  
Since strscan is a default gem, you can either remove your dependency on it or try updating to a newer version of bundler that supports strscan as a default gem. (Gem::LoadError)
```

where `bundle -v   Bundler version 2.3.13`

regards a dependency which is not directly invoked in the Gemfile.  The Gemfile.lock does state `strscan (3.0.3)`  strscan is invoked by `net-imap (0.2.3)`

```
gem update --system
gem update bundler
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

does not solve the issue.

How can this versioning matter be ironed out? Be it via explicit verisoning or removal of dependency

Comment: Your best bet is to separate your system Ruby from your app Ruby with a Ruby version manager (rvm, rbenv, asdf, ...)

Comment: rbenv is installed  `rbenv 1.1.2-20-g143b2c9`

Comment: Are you using gemsets?

Comment: no gemsets are in use

Comment: Thats a strange dependency. [StringScanner](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) has been a part of the Ruby STDlib since forever.

Answer (score 7):

Just use this command on your SSH server

`gem update strscan`

to check current `strscan` version use

`gem list | grep strscan`

Answer (score 3):

#### Pin `strscan` gem version to 3.0.1.

In your `Gemfile`:

```rb
gem "strscan", "3.0.1"
```

Then `bundle update` to update your `Gemfile.lock`.

That should fix the issue.

Based on [this](https://github.com/ruby/psych/pull/534), I *believe* this will be fixed in Ruby 3.1.3+ and you should be able to remove this line from your `Gemfile` but I'm not sure.

What's tricky about this is we only ran into the issue in Production and Staging environments, not Development or Test environments.

Another good reason to deploy everything to Staging first, test and then deploy to Production.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon similar issue after upgrading to Rails v7.1.3. We got the following error on our CI:

/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.2.2/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:309:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated mutex_m 0.1.2, but your Gemfile requires mutex_m 0.2.0. Since mutex_m is a default gem, you can either remove your dependency on it or try updating to a newer version of bundler that supports mutex_m as a default gem. (Gem::LoadError)

The culprit was spring, I've added `DISABLE_SPRING` env variable into our CI config and the error went away.

Related spring issue: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/697

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much have to monkey patch the gemfile.lock to use 3.0.0 instead!
https://openbuildservice.org/2022/05/11/post-mortem/

Comment: Note - for some reason i actually had to edit it to use 3.0.1 (even though i got 3.0.0 installed :s)